# Caused by android.security.KeyStoreException: Memory allocation failed

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, keystore, encrypted-shared-preference

```
 private var masterKey = MasterKey.Builder(applicationContext)
        .setKeyScheme(MasterKey.KeyScheme.AES256_GCM)
        .build()
    var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences = EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(
        applicationContext,
        ENCRYPTED_SHARED_PREFERENCE,
        masterKey,
        EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefKeyEncryptionScheme.AES256_SIV,
        EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefValueEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM
    )
```

Caused by android.security.KeyStoreException: Memory allocation failed

Caused by android.security.KeyStoreException: Memory allocation failed
at android.security.KeyStore.getKeyStoreException(KeyStore.java:850)
at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreKeyGeneratorSpi.engineGenerateKey(AndroidKeyStoreKeyGeneratorSpi.java:324)
at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.generateKey(KeyGenerator.java:612)
at androidx.security.crypto.MasterKeys.generateKey(MasterKeys.java:145)
at androidx.security.crypto.MasterKeys.getOrCreate(MasterKeys.java:100)
at androidx.security.crypto.MasterKey$Builder$Api23Impl.build(MasterKey.java:380)
at androidx.security.crypto.MasterKey$Builder.build(MasterKey.java)
at com.leap.core_ielts_android.sharedprefs.EncryptedSharedPreference.(EncryptedSharedPreference.kt:17)
at com.leap.core_ielts_android.CoreUtils.addEncryptedTokenIfNotExist(CoreUtils.kt:62)
at com.knudge.me.activity.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:121)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1155)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5949)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:200)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1673)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)

Answer (score 0):

add masterKey builder

```
.setUserAuthenticationRequired(false)
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder#setUserAuthenticationRequired(boolean)